# laravel mongodb where clause on nested document

Tags: php, mongodb, collections, laravel-5, mongodb-query

i have a collection "website" which data structure is like

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 57beda7f0640fd14ca5cc307
)
[website] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 57beda3d279871c80e8b4567
)
[url] => https://acb.com
[meta_tags] => Array (
    [description] => 
    [title] => Login 
    [title_length] => 18    
)
```

ans same i have 10 rows of data.

now i am using laravel eloquent and i need to fetch all data which website is 57beda3d279871c80e8b4567 and title is empty or null.

who should i update my query for title attribute

```
 $this->website->where('website', $website)->get();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Add another **where** condition:

```
$this->website
->where('website', $website)
->where('meta_tags.title', '=','')
->whereNull('meta_tags.title')
->get();
```

Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries